# Ctypes : C stubs generation function with funptr

Tags: ocaml

I am playing with the OCaml Ctypes library when I try to bind C function pointer I have an error message saying : `Error: Unbound value funptr`

I have a functor in which are defining the bindings for my lib:

**ecore_evas_functor.ml**

```
open Ctypes

module Bindings (F : Cstubs.FOREIGN) = struct
  open F
  let eina_bool =
    view ~read:((<>) 0) ~write:(fun b -> compare b false) int

  let ecore_main_loop_begin =
    foreign "ecore_main_loop_begin" (void @-> returning void)
  let ecore_main_loop_quit =
    foreign "ecore_main_loop_quit" (void @-> returning void)
  let ecore_evas_init =
    foreign "ecore_evas_init" (void @-> returning eina_bool)
  let ecore_evas_shutdown =
    foreign "ecore_evas_shutdown" (void @-> returning eina_bool)

  type ecore_evas = unit ptr
  let ecore_evas : ecore_evas typ = ptr void

  let ecore_evas_new =
    foreign "ecore_evas_new" (string_opt @-> int @-> int @-> int @-> int @-> string_opt @-> returning ecore_evas)

  let ecore_evas_title_set =
    foreign "ecore_evas_title_set" (ecore_evas @-> string_opt @-> returning void)

  let ecore_evas_show =
    foreign "ecore_evas_show" (ecore_evas @-> returning void)

  let ecore_evas_free =
    foreign "ecore_evas_free" (ecore_evas @-> returning void)

  let ecore_evas_alpha_set =
    foreign "ecore_evas_alpha_set" (ecore_evas @-> eina_bool @-> returning void)
end
```

When I use this functor, I am able to produce C stubs with .

**stubs_generators.ml**

```
(* corebuild -pkg ctypes.foreign,ctypes.stubs -lflags -cclib,-lecore_evas -lflags -cclib,-lecore stubs_generator.native *)
let _ =
  let prefix = "ecore_evas_stubs" in
  let generate_ml, generate_c = ref false, ref false in
  Arg.(parse [ ("-ml", Set generate_ml, "Generate ML");
                ("-c", Set generate_c, "Generate C") ])
    (fun _ -> failwith "unexpected anonymous argument")
    "stubgen [-ml|-c]";
  match !generate_ml, !generate_c with
  | false, false
  | true, true ->
    failwith "Exactly one of -ml and -c must be specified"
  | true, false ->
    Cstubs.write_ml Format.std_formatter ~prefix (module Ecore_evas.Bindings)
  | false, true ->
      print_endline "#include <Ecore.h>\n#include <Ecore_Evas.h>";
    Cstubs.write_c Format.std_formatter ~prefix (module Ecore_evas.Bindings)
```

After that I wanted my module to be able to handle callbacks for a test so I add this in **ecore_evas_functor.ml** :

```
let ecore_evas_event_cb = ecore_evas @-> returning void

let ecore_evas_callback_delete_request_set =
  foreign "ecore_evas_callback_delete_request_set" (ecore_evas @-> funptr ecore_evas_event_cb @-> returning void)
```

**ecore_evas_functor.ml**

```
open Ctypes

module Bindings (F : Cstubs.FOREIGN) = struct
  open F
  let eina_bool =
    view ~read:((<>) 0) ~write:(fun b -> compare b false) int

  let ecore_main_loop_begin =
    foreign "ecore_main_loop_begin" (void @-> returning void)
  (* same code as before *)

  let ecore_evas_alpha_set =
    foreign "ecore_evas_alpha_set" (ecore_evas @-> eina_bool @-> returning void)

  let ecore_evas_event_cb = ecore_evas @-> returning void

  let ecore_evas_callback_delete_request_set =
    foreign "ecore_evas_callback_delete_request_set" (ecore_evas @-> funptr ecore_evas_event_cb @-> returning void)
end
```

I have this compile error:

```
corebuild -pkg ctypes.foreign,ctypes.stubs -lflags -cclib,-lecore_evas -lflags -cclib,-lecore stubs_generator.native
+ ocamlfind ocamlc -c -w A-4-33-40-41-42-43-34-44 -strict-sequence -g -bin-annot -short-paths -thread -package ctypes.foreign,ctypes.stubs -package core -ppx 'ppx-jane -as-ppx' -o ecore_evas.cmo ecore_evas.ml
File "ecore_evas.ml", line 38, characters 69-75:
Error: Unbound value funptr
Command exited with code 2.
Hint: Recursive traversal of subdirectories was not enabled for this build,
  as the working directory does not look like an ocamlbuild project (no
  '_tags' or 'myocamlbuild.ml' file). If you have modules in subdirectories,
  you should add the option "-r" or create an empty '_tags' file.

  To enable recursive traversal for some subdirectories only, you can use the
  following '_tags' file:

      true: -traverse
      <dir1> or <dir2>: traverse

Compilation unsuccessful after building 3 targets (1 cached) in 00:00:00.
```

** edit **

I had a simple module at first in order to generate the bindings which was working:

**ecore_evas.ml**

```
open Ctypes
open Foreign

let eina_bool =
  view ~read:((<>) 0) ~write:(fun b -> compare b false) int

let ecore_main_loop_begin =
  foreign "ecore_main_loop_begin" (void @-> returning void)
let ecore_main_loop_quit =
  foreign "ecore_main_loop_quit" (void @-> returning void)
let ecore_evas_init =
  foreign "ecore_evas_init" (void @-> returning eina_bool)
let ecore_evas_shutdown =
  foreign "ecore_evas_shutdown" (void @-> returning eina_bool)

type ecore_evas = unit ptr
let ecore_evas : ecore_evas typ = ptr void

let ecore_evas_new =
  foreign "ecore_evas_new" (string_opt @-> int @-> int @-> int @-> int @-> string_opt @-> returning ecore_evas)

let ecore_evas_title_set =
  foreign "ecore_evas_title_set" (ecore_evas @-> string_opt @-> returning void)

let ecore_evas_show =
  foreign "ecore_evas_show" (ecore_evas @-> returning void)

let ecore_evas_free =
  foreign "ecore_evas_free" (ecore_evas @-> returning void)

let ecore_evas_alpha_set =
  foreign "ecore_evas_alpha_set" (ecore_evas @-> eina_bool @-> returning void)
let ecore_evas_event_cb = ecore_evas @-> returning void

let ecore_evas_callback_delete_request_set =
  foreign "ecore_evas_callback_delete_request_set" (ecore_evas @-> funptr ecore_evas_event_cb @-> returning void)
```

Comment: You may want to trim this down to a [mcve]. Include only the code needed to reproduce the error message.

Comment: @miken32, I have "reorganized" my question, unfortunately I am afraid that this is the minimum code I could offer because the bindings that I done are the minimals functions in order to create a working test : https://github.com/cedlemo/ocaml_ffi_evas/blob/master/c_functions_pointers/ecore_evas_window.ml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not supported yet :

https://github.com/ocamllabs/ocaml-ctypes/issues/278